# MSBuild error MSB4057 The targer "_CopyWebApplication" does not exist

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm migrating a build file that ran perfectly in Visual Studio 2010.'m Now using the 2013 Express version.

When trying to compile a project as the command line below returns the error:
**MSBuild error MSB4057 The targer "_CopyWebApplication" does not exist in project**

Code:

```
<exec program="${msbuild.exe}" failonerror="true" workingdir=".">
  <arg value="IntegradorMegasul/IntegradorMegasul.csproj" />
  <arg value="/p:Configuration=Debug" />
  <arg value="/p:Platform=${build.platform}"/>      
  <arg value="/t:ResolveReferences" />
  <arg value="/t:_CopyWebApplication" />
  <arg value="/t:TransformWebConfig" />
  <arg value="/p:OutputPath=${publicar.output}" />
  <arg value="/p:OutDir=${publicar.out}" />
  <arg value="/p:WebProjectOutputDir=${publicar.pub}" />
</exec>
```